# Alamofire Connect to Localhost

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to connect to my localhost (homestead with laravel) to test my swift app. Therefore I use Alamofire to send data via my API to be saved in my database. When I connect to my staging server (in the cloud) everything works fine. But when I want to connect to my local machine (192.168.10.10) it doesn't work through the iOS app. Using the same connection via POSTMAN does work fine and I can access everything.

How do I need to configure Alamofire, that I can use my localhost IP to connect to my test database?

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://192.168.10.10/v1"

    // == AUTHENTICIATION ==
    case RegisterUser([String:AnyObject]) 

    // match URLRequest routes to Alamofire methods
    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        var method: Alamofire.Method {
            switch self {

                // == AUTHENTICATION RESOURCE ==
            case .RegisterUser:
                return .POST
            }
        }

        let result: (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) = {

            switch self {

                // == AUTHENTICATION RESOURCE ==
            case .RegisterUser(let newUser):
                return ("mfusers", newUser)
            }()

        // Generate URL Request
        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!

        // Append the path components from the result
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(result.path))

        // Create URLRequest inclunding the encoded parameters        
        var parametersEncoding:Alamofire.ParameterEncoding {
            switch method {
            case .GET:
                return .URL
            case .POST, .PUT:
                return .JSON
            default:
                return .JSON
            }
        }

        let encoding = parametersEncoding
        let (encodedRequest, _) = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: result.parameters)
        encodedRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
        return encodedRequest
    }
}
```